# Array of images not loading into UICollectionView from data but do from simple array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uicollectionview

this is a strange one that's really got me stumped! So I hope someone can help.

I have a CollectionView set up in IB all works ok with the following array:

```
_imageArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"shop.JPG",@"shop1.jpg",@"shop2.jpg",@"Turkish_Tea.png", nil];
```

However when I load my document directory images into the array they don't load into the CollectioView at all?

Here is where I get my images from the apps folder into the array and the NSLog showing they are there!

```
    NSString *extension = @"png";
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];

    NSLog(@"files array - %@", directoryContent);
    NSMutableArray *fileNameArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:directoryContent.count];
    NSString *fileName;

    for (fileName in directoryContent) {
        if ([[fileName pathExtension] isEqualToString:extension]) {
            [fileNameArray addObject:fileName];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"Images added to array are %@",fileNameArray);

    2018-02-02 23:09:23.326146+0000 Bodrum[579:117199] Images added to array are (
    "2018-02-02 20:59:06.png",
    "2018-02-02 19:58:23.png",
    "2018-02-02 19:58:08.png",
    "2018-02-02 22:16:27.png",
    "2018-02-02 22:17:55.png",
    "2018-02-02 22:16:12.png",
    "2018-02-02 19:57:45.png")


Am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks in advance



Whole code snippet as requested:

    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    NSString *extension = @"png";
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];

    NSLog(@"files array - %@", directoryContent);
    NSMutableArray *fileNameArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:directoryContent.count];
    NSString *fileName;

    for (fileName in directoryContent) {
        if ([[fileName pathExtension] isEqualToString:extension]) {
            [fileNameArray addObject:fileName];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"Images added to array are %@",fileNameArray);

    _imageArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"shop.JPG",@"shop1.jpg",@"shop2.jpg",@"Turkish_Tea.png", nil];//fileNameArray

    NSLog(@"Image Array is %@",_imageArray);

    NSLog(@"Image Array contains %lu",_imageArray.count);

    [self.collectionView reloadData];

}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{

    return _imageArray.count;



}

- (__kindof UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];

    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[_imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView;
{
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You need to show relevant code for your collection view.

Comment: "However when I load my document directory images into the array they don't load into the CollectioView at all?"  Que?  There's no sign of a collection view object as long as one sees your code.

Comment: Can you try to rename your image name to something without all those colons and space. Try to have an image with name like image1.png and see if it loads.

Comment: Here is the entire code that loads the images in view did load and the collectinview. (As you'll see I'm testing at the moment with a simple array of images in my bundle but //fileNameArray is what I'm trying in _imageArray = fileNameArray?

Comment: Hi @MilanGupta, thanks for the advice, I've changed the format of the image names as follows: 2018-02-03 10:36:50.345919+0000 Bodrum[794:213929] Image Array is (
    "20180203103649.png",
    "20180203103556.png",
    "20180203103536.png"
) Still doesn't work?!

Answer (score 0):

After much searching and playing around I changed this section:

```
for (fileName in directoryContent) {
    if ([[fileName pathExtension] isEqualToString:extension]) {
        [fileNameArray addObject:fileName];
    }
}
```

to this following:

```
for (fileName in contents) {

    if ([[fileName pathExtension] isEqualToString:extension])
    {

        [fileNameArray addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName ]]];
    }
}
```

and I know have an array with my UIImages in!